# How to replace the "localizeddate" filter from twig/extensions

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

I'm currently updating my projects to Symfony 5.1 (where I was previously using Symfony 4.1).

When updating I noticed that I can't install the package `twig/extensions` anymore, which means I can't use the `|localizeddate` filter.

This has basically already been discussed here: [Composer can't install Twig Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340979/composer-cant-install-twig-extensions)

```
- twig/extensions v1.5.0 requires twig/twig ~1.27|~2.0
```

According to my composer.lock file, 3.0.3 is installed

```
        ...
        {
            "name": "twig/twig",
            "version": "v3.0.3",
            ...
```

But just saying something isn't available anymore does not fix the problem

---

My only use case right now is the following code:

```
{{ comment.publishedAt|localizeddate('medium', 'short', null, 'UTC') }}
```

And here is the docs page, for those unfamiliar: https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html#localizeddate

**Is there another filter or simply another way of how to replace this?**

Comment: you also could have copied the code for localizeddate: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/src/IntlExtension.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `twig/extensions` got split up into multiple smaller projects.

So for this case, I had to do

```sh
composer require twig/intl-extra
```

(See: https://github.com/twigphp/intl-extra)

And replace the code with:

```
{{ comment.publishedAt|format_datetime('medium', 'short', null, 'UTC') }}
```

(Whether the code works, still has to be tested)